# perl script on text-files

Tags: file, perl, text

I have a PERL script that is supposed to do "something" on the text files contained in a folder. From the script name I can guess what is supposed to do, but in my opinion doesn't do anything(I cannot see any change to the texts files when I execute from a git bash shell on windows).

What I would like to know is if is doing in reality something and if the result could be different using another perl interpreter or OS.

```
#!perl

$|++;

use strict;
use File::Find;
my ($cnt, $uxcnt);

print "Doing something on files on @ARGV ...";

find(\&wanted, @ARGV);

print " done something for ($uxcnt/$cnt) files\n";

sub wanted {
  $cnt++;
  my $file = $_;
  if(-T $file) {
    $uxcnt++;
    open FILE, $file or warn "Warning: Couldn't open $file: $!\n";
    my @buf;
    push @buf, $_ while <FILE>;
    close FILE;
    open FILE, ">$file" or warn "Warning: Couldn't open $file: $!\n";
    binmode FILE;
    print FILE @buf;
    close FILE;
  } 
}
```

Comment: It does some strange things (report failing to open a file but then keeps on going like it succeeded?) and rather old idioms that aren't recommended (bareword file handles instead of lexical, not using three argument `open`, no `use warnings;`, etc... At least it has `use strict;`) but it looks like the intent is to convert Windows line endings to Unix ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Update:** As people have pointed out in the comments, I've missed something important here - when run on Windows, it will convert Windows (CRLF) line-endings to Unix (LF) ones.]

It does nothing useful.

It looks for all of the files it can find under the directories that it is given on the command line. For each file it finds, it works out (or, more accurately, guesses) whether the file is a text file. If the file is a text file, then it reads all of the text from the file into an array called `@buf` and then overwrites the file with the data in `@buf`.

So basically it reads the data from every text file it finds and then writes that data back to the original files.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I think (but I don't know perl so I asked). Now the name of the script is "unixise_dir.pl",so, I guess is supposed to transform something(linefeed?) from windows to unix format(hence the second part of my question)

Comment: I'm not convinced I agree with this answer. There's probably some magic being triggered so that dos->unix conversion is done while reading the file. For all you know, it only does so when run on a Windows or on a Mac or on some other platform, but nothing on other platforms, which is why it might seem to do nothing. The name of the script strongly suggests this interpretation, and I would assume it worked wherever it was first developed, if nowhere else.

Comment: On a Windows system, it will convert CRLF line endings to LF

Comment: Thanks to everyone. Effectively running the script on Windows using ActivePerl I obtain the desired behavior: the CRLF are converted in LF for all the text files. The same doesn't happen when executed on Windows BUT using the perl interpreter present in the Git Bash console, where there is no convertion.